# jquery - make sticky fixed position div stop scrolling at footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position, sticky

I have the following `jquery` script to make a fixed position for a div after a certain amount of scrolling. That works great but I need this div to stop scrolling when it hits the footer div, otherwise it overlaps it. Any help would be appreciated. http://wzrd3.wpengine.com/listings/

```
jQuery(function($) {
function fixDiv() {

  var $cache = $('#sabai-directory-listings-geolocate-directory-map-container'); 
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 160) 
    $cache.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'padding-top': '90px', 'width': '416px', 'height': '528px', 'bottom': 'auto'}); 
  else
    $cache.css({'position': 'relative', 'top': '0', 'height': '528px', 'padding-top': '0px',});
}

$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
fixDiv();
});
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: take the height of the footer div, minus from document height and when scrollTop reaches that level, set the css to fix that div just above the foooter

Comment: I added a link above to the site so you can see what I'm talking about, it really needs to stop when it hits the pagination div (.sabai-directory-pagination) but the concept is the same.